# Can't install Workbench on Surface Pro 3

Tags: workbench

I've been trying to install Wolfram Workbench 2 for a few days on a Surface Pro 3 i5 256 Mb, Windows 8.1, Mathematica 10.0.1, Java 8, without success, I'm getting a bit desperate. 
For the Eclipse version I've tried Kepler and Luna.

The strange thing is that it used to work on a similar configuration but with a Surface Pro 2. I've tried also the solution from Rolf Mertig on this site.

Has somebody had this problem and managed to get it running ?

The error I get is

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching test.nb (1)".
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLOpenString(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLOpenString(Native Method)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.<init>(NativeLink.java:113)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkFactory.createMathLink0(MathLinkFactory.java:263)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkFactory.createMathLink(MathLinkFactory.java:190)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink0(MathLinkFactory.java:167)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink(MathLinkFactory.java:65)
    at com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.mathlink.MathLinkInitializer.<init>(MathLinkInitializer.java:23)
    at com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.mathlink.MathLinkInitializer.initMathLink(MathLinkInitializer.java:46)
    at com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.launch.InterpreterLink.createInterpreterLink(InterpreterLink.java:222)
    at com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.launch.MathematicaConsoleLaunch.launchOperation(MathematicaConsoleLaunch.java:374)
    at com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.launch.MathematicaConsoleLaunch.launch(MathematicaConsoleLaunch.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: Were you using MMA 10.0.1 on your Surface Pro 2?  If not I personally wouldn't bother with WB2 for MMA 10.0.x, as they don't seem to play nice together (at least for my purpose/syntax).  Might be worth trying with MMA 9.x if you haven't already.

Comment: Yes I was, and I'm using mm10's Association/Dataset, so I need mm10.

Comment: @faysou you could try contacting support and asking for the Workbench 3.0 beta. This issue should be fixed in WB3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't normally use Workbench, but I am pretty certain you can resolve the issue by just installing v9.

M- 10 on Windows changed a number of things under the hood.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Mathematica.SE. This seems more appropriate as a comment than an answer, since it does not really answer the question of how to set up WB2 with V10 or whether it is possible.

Comment: Any other answer is something I would tell tech support not to suggest.  That doesn't preclude them from using v10 afterwards.

Comment: It worked like a charm thank you very much for you help.